# How to change the background color on a view from different activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, nullpointerexception

I need to change the background color on the navigation's header, when i findViewById() in MainActivity I get null.

This is the navigation header,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nav_second_header_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#00aeef"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/school"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/schatkamer" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_second_header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/school"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/school"
        android:text="account name"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/school" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is The code in onCreate MainActivity

```
        second_bar_header = findViewById(R.id.nav_second_header_bg); //this id returns null
        second_bar_header.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("00ff00"));

        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.nav_second_header_text); // this is null
        tv.setText("hi");
```

Comment: Silly question, did you forget to call setContentView first?

Comment: use `navigationView.findViewById()`.

Comment: yes of course I set the ContentView... What a silly question

Answer (score 0):

YOu should try something like this

```
    NavigationView navigationView =  findViewById(R.id.you_nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    TextView username =  header.findViewById(R.id.nav_second_header_text);
    username.setText("Hi");

    second_bar_header = header.findViewById(R.id.nav_second_header_bg); 
    second_bar_header.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("00ff00"));
```